# Lifetime errors with a simple resource Allocator struct

Tags: rust, lifetime, object-lifetime, lifetime-scoping

I'm trying to make a simple allocator that allocates and deallocates buffers from a fixed pool of buffers.

```
struct AllocatedMemory<'a> {
    mem: &'a mut [u8],
    next: Option<&'a mut AllocatedMemory<'a>>,
}

struct Alloc<'a> {
    glob: Option<&'a mut AllocatedMemory<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Alloc<'a> {
    fn alloc_cell(mut self: &mut Alloc<'a>) -> &mut AllocatedMemory<'a> {
        let rest: Option<&'a mut AllocatedMemory<'a>>;
        match self.glob {
            Some(ref mut root_cell) => {
                rest = std::mem::replace(&mut root_cell.next, None);
            }
            None => rest = None,
        }
        match std::mem::replace(&mut self.glob, rest) {
            Some(mut root_cell) => {
                return root_cell;
            }
            None => panic!("OOM"),
        }
    }

    fn free_cell(mut self: &mut Alloc<'a>, mut val: &'a mut AllocatedMemory<'a>) {
        match std::mem::replace(&mut self.glob, None) {
            Some(mut x) => {
                let discard = std::mem::replace(&mut val.next, Some(x));
                let rest: Option<&'a mut AllocatedMemory<'a>>;
            }
            None => {}
        }
        self.glob = Some(val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer0: [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024];
    let mut buffer1: [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024];
    {
        let mut cell1: AllocatedMemory = AllocatedMemory {
            mem: &mut buffer1[0..1024],
            next: None,
        };
        let mut cell0: AllocatedMemory = AllocatedMemory {
            mem: &mut buffer0[0..1024],
            next: None,
        };
        let mut allocator = Alloc { glob: None };
        allocator.free_cell(&mut cell1); //populate allocator with a cell
        allocator.free_cell(&mut cell0); //populate allocator with another cell (why does this fail?)

        let mut x = allocator.alloc_cell();
        allocator.free_cell(x);
        let mut y = allocator.alloc_cell();
        let mut z = allocator.alloc_cell();
        allocator.free_cell(y);
        allocator.free_cell(z);
    }
}
```

The error is

```
error: `cell0` does not live long enough
     allocator.free_cell(&mut cell0); //populate allocator with another cell (why does this fail?)
```

when I simply remove `cell0` and only have `cell1` available to my cell pool then the following errors happens:

```
error: allocator does not live long enough
         let mut x = allocator.alloc_cell();
                     ^~~~~~~~~
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 46:69...
                                                          next: None};
         let mut cell0 : AllocatedMemory = AllocatedMemory{mem: &mut buffer0[0..1024],
                                                          next: None};
         let mut allocator = Alloc {glob : None};
         allocator.free_cell(&mut cell1); //populate allocator with a cell
         //allocator.free_cell(&mut cell0); //populate allocator with another cell (why does this fail?)

note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 2 at 49:48
         let mut allocator = Alloc {glob : None};
         allocator.free_cell(&mut cell1); //populate allocator with a cell
         //allocator.free_cell(&mut cell0); //populate allocator with another cell (why does this fail?)

         let mut x = allocator.alloc_cell();
         allocator.free_cell(x);
               ...
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to fix this code so it compiles and may have 2+ items in the free list?

I want to populate a list of references to arrays and then be able to pop them - use them for a while and place the used/finished value back onto the freelist.

The motivation here is to build a library that uses the `#![nostd]` directive, so it needs an allocator interface to operate properly.

Comment: I have not looked at it in detail but this looks like a linked list. A typical beginner mistake when trying build a linked list is for the parent node to borrow the child node with & or &mut rather than owning it with Box<Node>. Is this of any help?

Comment: That is helpful; however, I want to do this without requiring on the libstd crate...so Box, I believe, won't work for me here.

Comment: That said, I'm happy to have the lifetime of everything borrowed on the list to exist on the stack before anything is used. So I'm not actually violating ownership here... the design is has a bunch of cells with the same lifetime living outside of the scope of the list structure. Then the list structure can simply make them refer to one another.  The problem that starblue pointed out is that you can't have 2 items on the stack come alive at "the same time" so then you can't have the later item refer to the earlier item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to starblue's pointer, I decided to force the lifetimes of the allocator and cells to be the same by placing them into a struct and putting that struct on the stack.
The final result is here:

```
// This code is placed in the public domain
struct AllocatedMemory<'a> {
   mem : &'a mut [u8],
   next : Option<&'a mut AllocatedMemory <'a> >,
}
struct Alloc<'a> {
  glob : Option<&'a mut AllocatedMemory <'a> >,
}

impl<'a> Alloc <'a> {
  fn alloc_cell(self : &mut Alloc<'a>) -> &'a mut AllocatedMemory<'a> {
      match self.glob {
        Some(ref mut glob_next) => {
             let rest : Option<&'a mut AllocatedMemory <'a> >;
             match glob_next.next {
                 Some(ref mut root_cell) => {
                    rest = std::mem::replace(&mut root_cell.next, None);
                 },
                 None => rest = None,
             }
             match std::mem::replace(&mut glob_next.next, rest) {
                Some(mut root_cell) =>
                {
                 return root_cell;
                },
                None => panic!("OOM"),
             }
        },
        None => panic!("Allocator not initialized"),
     }
  }
  fn free_cell(self : &mut Alloc<'a>,
               mut val : & 'a mut AllocatedMemory<'a>) {
      match self.glob {
          Some(ref mut glob_next) => {
              match std::mem::replace(&mut glob_next.next ,None) {
                  Some(mut x) => {
                      let _discard = std::mem::replace(&mut val.next, Some(x));
                  },
                  None => {},
              }
              glob_next.next = Some(val);
           },
           None => panic!("Allocator not initialized"),
      }
  }
}
struct AllocatorGlobalState<'a>{
  cell1 : AllocatedMemory<'a>,
  cell0 : AllocatedMemory<'a>,
  sentinel : AllocatedMemory<'a>,
  allocator :Alloc<'a>,

}
fn main() {
  let mut buffer0 : [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024];
  let mut buffer1 : [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024];
  let mut sentinel_buffer : [u8; 1] = [0];
  let mut ags : AllocatorGlobalState = AllocatorGlobalState {
  cell1 : AllocatedMemory{mem: &mut buffer1[0..1024],
                          next: None},
  cell0 : AllocatedMemory{mem: &mut buffer0[0..1024],
                          next: None},
  sentinel : AllocatedMemory{mem: &mut sentinel_buffer[0..1], next: None},
  allocator : Alloc {glob : None},
  };
  ags.allocator.glob = Some(&mut ags.sentinel);
  ags.allocator.free_cell(&mut ags.cell1);
  ags.allocator.free_cell(&mut ags.cell0);
  {
  let mut x = ags.allocator.alloc_cell();
  x.mem[0] = 4;
  let mut y = ags.allocator.alloc_cell();
  y.mem[0] = 4;
  ags.allocator.free_cell(y);
  let mut z = ags.allocator.alloc_cell();
  z.mem[0] = 8;
  //y.mem[0] = 5; // <-- this is an error (use after free)
  }
}
```

I needed to add the sentinel struct to avoid double borrowing of ags.allocator when doing multiple allocations.

```
cell.rs:65:19: 65:32 help: run `rustc --explain E0499` to see a detailed explanation
cell.rs:62:19: 62:32 note: previous borrow of `ags.allocator` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `ags.allocator` until the borrow ends
```

With the sentinel being stored in Alloc I can guarantee that I never modify `glob` after the function returns.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you always use the same lifetime `'a`. This forces `cell0` and `cell1` to have the same lifetime, which is not possible, because one has to be defined first. If you read the error message carefully you can see that it complains about the lifetime of the second not including the statement defining the first cell.

I don't know if this is a bug or misfeature which implements lifetimes to strictly, or if it is inherent in the lifetime type system (I haven't seen a formal definition yet).

I also don't know how to fix it. I fixed a similar problem in some example code I had by introducing additional lifetime variables, but I couldn't make it work for your code.